# Find runs of consecutive values in int array

Tags: c++, arrays, search

Let's say I have this integer array of separate integer elements:

```
111100010011010
```

I'd like to find out if there exists `0000` in this array, which obviously does not, but `000` exists. Same goes for other lengths of consecutive runs.

I know this is easily done with strings, there are built in functions for this, but is there something built in which accomplishes what I want to do?

Or is there another easy method I overlooked? All I can come up with are complicated non efficient algorithms going through the array and saving values in a temporary other array.

Comment: What are you trying to solve, like at a higher level? What do you mean by "elements?" Are those just bits, or are they separate integers? Is your query `0000` *always* a series of the same digit (for example could it be described as `{ digit_value, count }`)? Could your search query be `010111`? Do you know about bitwise operations like shifting and `&`, `|`, et al.?

Comment: `int array = {1, 1, 0, 0, ...}` Those are separate integer elements in an array, all either 1 or 0. 

On a higher level I wanna check if a given sequence is a Maximum Length Sequence. I just wanted to start checking if `0000` exists in a 4 length MLS, which must not exist.

I do know about bitwise operations.

Comment: It's still not clear what you're trying to achieve. Do you want to find the longest run or check for the existence of a given run or find out if a given run is a longest run or something else? It might be better to present your non-efficient algorithm as code.

Comment: Right now I literally only want to check if ´0000´ exists in this sequence.

I have not yet written down my algorithm as code, but if it helps, here is what I ultimately want to achieve: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_length_sequence#Run_property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to save values to a temporary array.

All you need to do is keep track of the largest length found (initially zero) and the location of its first element (initially NULL if you use a pointer to indicate that).

Then walk through the array until you find the value of interest.   Count the number of consecutive occurrences.   If that number exceeds the maximum length found, set the location to point at the first one found.

Repeat until end of array is reached.

Done.    If the largest length found is zero, it means there were no occurrences of the value sought.

No, I'm not going to write code for the above.  The description of the approach is enough.

There are also plenty of alternative options using standard algorithms

Comment: Its a pretty simple algorithm and O(n) complexity.  Can't get much better than that :)

Comment: Thanks, this is simpler than what I had in mind! This also answers my question if there is something built in C++ which achieves this.

Answer (score 2):

Just for the record, another way is to use use [std::search](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search).

```
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

const int elements[] = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0 };
const int test1[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
const int test2[] = { 0, 0, 0 };

auto it1 = std::search(begin(elements), end(elements), begin(test1), end(test1));
auto it2 = std::search(begin(elements), end(elements), begin(test2), end(test2));

std::cout << "Test 0000: " << (it1 == end(elements) ? "no" : "yes") << "\n";
std::cout << "Test 000: " << (it2 == end(elements) ? "no" : "yes") << "\n";
```

Prints out:

```
Test 0000: no
Test 000: yes
```

Even easier if your array is a standard container, like std::array or vector.